# SQL Cannot patch the latest CU4 for SQL 2014 SP3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, patching

I cannot patch the latest CU4 for SQL 2014 SP3. Checked "view installed program", 4500181 is already installed.

[image]

but when I use "Select @@version" against my SQL instance, it still shows "12.0.6259.0" which is SP3-CU3. Has anyone encountered this before and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: what error do you get ?

Comment: Once I try to patch CU4. This message shows up: The version of SQL Server instance MSSQLSERVER does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. The installed SQL Server product version is 12.0.2000.8, and the expected SQL Server version is 12.3.6024.0.

Comment: first patch with sp3 then with cu4 - since it tells the product version is 12.0.2000.8 - which is RTM.

Comment: The build number is already 6259...which is already SP3-CU3

Comment: Did you restart SQL since the last patch?

Comment: What do your bootstrap log files show?  These can generally be found in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120` and they should contain some more detailed error information.

Comment: @DBALUKEHUANG, do you mean _expected SQL Server version is **12.0.6024.0**_? as per error message. the [Detail.txt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-2017) must give more information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% sure this is the cause of your issue, but this is too long for a comment.

This can occur if SQL Server components are installed similar to the following:

1. Install SQL Server Database Engine
2. Install a service pack
3. Install Reporting Services

At this point, the installer will refuse to install a post-SP CU due to the RTM version of Reporting Services.  Based on my investigation, a certain registry value gets reset to the RTM version when Reporting Services is installed, and this is what the installer is referring to.

The solution is to install the service pack again (SP3, in your case), which will update Reporting Services, and then you will be able to install the post-SP3 CU.

I would assume this would be the case for other components such as Analysis Services, but I have only run into this issue with Reporting Services.

Comment: Thank you Tony, I fixed it with re-install SP3 on it.

Comment: This can also occur if you install other features after the SP - Like full text search.